# Get value from JSON into HTML

Tags: javascript, json

```
function callLink(imageId) {
        $.getJSON('/GetData/GetImage?idImage=' + imageId, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
```

The JSON result when I run above code is

```
[
   {
      FileName:"10012816.jpeg"      ID:2591      TicketID:"10012816"
   },
   {
      FileName:"1562754508233.jpeg"      ID:2591      TicketID:"10012816"
   }
]
```

How can I get result from JSON above and put to html code. Like this

```
    @foreach (var item in data) {
//html code
<h6 class="mb-3">@item.FileName</h6>
...
<span class="badge badge-success r-30"><i class="icon-check mr-2"></i>@item.ID</span>

    }
```

Comment: What templating language are you using? Are the templates rendered in the backend (on the server), or in the browser?

Comment: I suggest that you learn about the DOM and the JavaScript functions that allow you to manipulate it.

Comment: @PatrickHund Just in the browser. I'm using MVC with HML and JS

Comment: Are you sure? `@foreach` and `@item` look like .net / ASP / Razor

Comment: var json = JSON.parse(data);

json[0].FileName
json[1].FileName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already provided the pseudo-code,

```
function callLink(imageId) {
    // as you are using `.getJSON` it's already formatted and you don't need `JSON.parse()`
    $.getJSON('/GetData/GetImage?idImage=' + imageId, function (data) {
        let output = '';
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            output += `<h6 class="mb-3">${data[i].fileName}</h6>`;
            output + = `..`;
            output + = `<span class="badge badge-success r-30"><i class="icon-check mr-2"></i>${data[i].ID}</span>`
        }
        // or some more useful code, like $(selector).html(output);
        alert(output);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create some html div

```
<div id="images-info"></div>
```

Append requested data into div

```
function callLink(imageId) {
    $.getJSON('/GetData/GetImage?idImage=' + imageId, function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $('#images-info').append('<div><h6 class="mb-3">'+ data[i].FileName +'</h6><span class="badge badge-success r-30"><i class="icon-check mr-2"></i>'+ data[i].ID +'</span></div>');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: DOM changes are expensive. It's better concatenate in memory and then append the final result in the DOM